# 2 react app in one website, one before login and one after login?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application, react-router-dom, router

I recently started learning react now I come to know that Facebook, Instagram and many more use react as frontend, but my question is when we go to instagram.com it give as page which behave as react spa but when we click on login it reload the page so how it is possible, how I can go to server while using react spa.
**for Example:-  if we take example of Instagram, if you first open Instagram page it behave as spa but when we fill form and click on login the page start reloading why?**

Comment: XHR (e.g. `fetch`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use several modules like `axios` or `fetch` to send the request from your client-side react application to the server. And you can redirect to the route according to the server responses.

Although a hard redirection (which causes the page to reload) is not recommended in a Single page application (SPA), you might wanna use [react-router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) for the same.

[Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) you can find the default `ajax` request sample provided in react documentation.

The [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) for `axios` library.

Comment: right i can use react-router-dom but if we take example of Instagram, if you first open Instagram page it behave as spa but when we fill form and click on login the page start reloading why?

Comment: This might be probably for an application to create session of the user once logged in, so that the session storage could behave as a logged in session